# Django forum submit not picked up by view

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms

So I thought when I press submit on the form (login page), that it would trigger my loginPage View and hit the `request.POST == 'Method'` becuase the form method is post but it is not doing this and I cannot login.
Bit confused since this worked before and I haven't touched it since. Any ideas guys?

I have a html login page called `login_register.html`. Below,

```
<form method="POST" action=""> 
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row center">
        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="off"></input>&nbsp;
        
        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off"></input>&nbsp;  

        <input type="submit" class="button-6-custom" value="login"></input>&nbsp;
    </div>
</form>
```

I have the urls.py file as well. Below,

```
path('login/', views.loginPage, name='login'),
```

And lastly, I have the View. Below,

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def loginPage(request):
    
        if request.method == 'POST':
            username = request.POST.get('username')
            password = request.POST.get('password')
    
            try:
                user = User.objects.get(username = user)
            except:
                print("Error - user / password incorrect, does not exist.")
    
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return redirect('home')
            else:
                print("User does not exist.")
    
        return render(request, 'base/login_register.html')
```

Comment: I tested it it's working on my local machine.

Comment: @CebrailYilmaz Thank you for testing it. It's very odd because it worked a day ago and I did not touch it. I don't think it's my browser since I did a hard refresh. A tricky one

Comment: Np. Btw, are you sure that the request is not hitting the if clause? Did you debug it correctly? (print functions aren't reliable)

Comment: @CebrailYilmaz I'm new to Python Django, I don't know much about debugging so I've just been using the print statement since it was easy. I should look into debugging now that you mention it. Thank you

Comment: You can look at logging library. First `import logging`, than `logging.error("your message")`, this is more reliable.

Answer (score 1):

You should complete the `action` attribute in the form:

```html
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'login' %}">
```

Note: the URL name can also be 'appname:login'. It depends on your URL setup.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving the issue. The search bar component was causing the issue. After playing around with it, I ended up moved it around in the folder and now it all works.
I think this is the result because before it was in the main.html where everything was static like links text etc. I moved it into my home.html where everything is dynamic and now it works.

Thanks everyone for your help. This was quite an odd one.